# Using Langrange multiplier to find min value

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

How do i find
$$
\min   \hspace{1cm} ||x||_2 - c^{T}x \\
\text{subject to}  \hspace{1cm}Ax = b
$$

My attempt: $x^T x - c^Tx - \lambda(Ax-b) = 0$. I need to differentiate this equation wrt $\lambda$ and $x$. But first, I am not sure this is the right formulation since $||x||_2 = \sqrt{x^Tx}$ rather than $x^Tx$. But if I use square root, I don't know how to proceed. What is the correct formulation?

Comment: Use the chain rule?

Comment: I can, but I wasn't also sure if that is the correct formulation.

Comment: What do you mean "correct formulation"? The definition of $\|x\|_2$ is $\sqrt{x^\top x}$. But none of us can verify whether $\|x\|_2$ or $\|x\|_2^2$ appears in the original problem.

Comment: It is $||x||_2$. But How do I proceed further? It becomes complicated after using chain rule.

Comment: You need to establish that a $\min$ exists and that a regularity condition exists at a $\min$ before you apply Lagrange. For example, if there is a feasible point and some $x \in \ker A$ such that $c^Tx >1$ then the cost is unbounded below.

Comment: @souravgoyal What do you know about $A$? I am assuming it is an $m \times n$ matrix with $m<n$... But if it is $n \times n $ and invertible, the admissible region reduces to one point...

Comment: @PierreCarre It is $m \times n$ and it is right invertible.

Comment: $D \|\cdot\|(x) = {x^T \over \|x\|}$, if that is what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

Suppose $x_0$ is a minimum norm solution to $Ax_0 = b$, then if
$Ax = b$ we have $x = x_0+ x-x_0$ with $x_0 \bot x-x_0$.

The problem becomes
$\min_{\delta \in \ker A} \sqrt{\|x_0\|^2+\|\delta\|^2}-c^T \delta -c^T x_0$.

Let $k= \sup_{\|h\| \le 1, h \in \ker A} |c^T h|$ and suppose $h$ is a unit vector in $\ker A$ such that $\|h\|=1$ and $k=c^T h$.

If $k>1$ and $t >0$ then since $\sqrt{\|x_0\|^2+\|th\|^2}-tc^T h \le \|x_0\| + t(1-k)$, we see that the cost is unbounded below and so there is no solution
as such.

If $ k \le 1$, since $-k\|\delta\| \le -c^T \delta $, we can assume that
$\delta$ is a multiple of $h$ to get the equivalent problem
$\inf_t \sqrt{\|x_0\|^2 + t^2} -t k$.

If $k=1$ then there is no minimiser, but it is clear that
$\inf_t \sqrt{\|x_0\|^2 + t^2} -t =0$.

If $k<1$ then $t={1 \over \sqrt{{1 \over k^2} -1} } \|x_0\|$.